# Want to plot the XY points randomly in a given area

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I want to plot the data points randomly like the one in the link below. 
The points will be plotted in the specific quadrant and in the specific year.
The number of points in a specific quadrant for the specific year is not fixed.

**https://iec.executiveboard.com/Members/VFI_2011_2014/VFI2011_2014.html**

Please help me about how to plot the points in HTML5 and css

Comment: I recommend D3.js: http://d3js.org/

Comment: I have used D3.js but I am not able to plot points randomly as in the link it is.